# R programming regarding types conversion

Tags: r, types

I am trying to convert the data types in order to correctly plot the data.

In my opinion, my codes are a little bit complex and are not effective.

Therefore, I would like to ask some advice for better codes.

Below are my codes.

```
pos <- as.matrix(read.delim("urc_pos",header=FALSE))
neg <- as.matrix(read.delim("urc_neg",header=FALSE))
rownames(pos) <- 1:nrow(pos)
pos_temp <- cbind("pos",pos[,3:42])
pos_temp_temp <- as.data.frame(pos_temp)
for(i in 2:41)
{
    pos_temp_temp[,i] <- as.numeric(as.character(pos_temp_temp[,i]))
}
```

urc_pos and urc_neg are my datasets.

For example, when I typed "is.numeric(pos[3,3])", it returned false because it was a vector. Therefore converting its data type to numeric type is necessary. After then, I assigned the row numbers and added label "pos" at the first column.

And below are the codes that convert the vector types to numerical type.
I think that it is a little bit complex and is unfavorable. Because I think that unnecessary procedures including converting data types ( data.frame -> character-> numerical) are involved in the for loops.

```
pos_temp_temp <- as.data.frame(pos_temp)
for(i in 2:41)
{
    pos_temp_temp[,i] <- as.numeric(as.character(pos_temp_temp[,i]))
}
```

Anyway, I got the what I intended. when I typed "is.numeric(pos_temp_temp[3,3])", it returned TRUE.

However, I want to get the better solutions for this problems. 
I am looking forward to your answer :D

Comment: If your codes are a little bit complex and are not effective, then that is one problem. If you are seeking your help, refine your question.

Comment: Please include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the following code:

```
pos_temp_temp<-as.numeric(as.character(pos_temp))
```

In general you should try to avoid loops whenever possbile.

Comment: Can you give an example of your data?